# Force html field value from ajax drop down and not user input

Tags: php, html, ajax

I have a field which produces a drop down that a user can select from as such

```
            $(function() {
              $('.serial_number').live('focus.autocomplete', function() { 
                $(this).autocomplete("/admin/includes/getinvoiceajax.php", {
                    width: 300,
                    matchContains: true,
                    mustMatch: true,
                    selectFirst: false
                }); 
              });
            });

<input type="text" name="serial_number[]" id="serial_number" class="serial_number" />
<input type="text" name="serial_number[]" id="serial_number" class="serial_number" />
<input type="text" name="serial_number[]" id="serial_number" class="serial_number" />
<input type="text" name="serial_number[]" id="serial_number" class="serial_number" />
```

I have set the mustMatch: true, so a user can only select what is from the dropdown list. Is there a way to not allow a duplicate selection from any of the other fields. Since I have a few of these fields it could possible allow the user to select the same value for multiple fields. I need to make sure they are unique.

Comment: so you want to mask the input? something like this http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/ or am i missing something?

Comment: no that was pertaining to my first question in which I edited it for another one. I figured out my first question with the answer below. Now I need to have the ability to prevent the user from including a value multiple times in the fields. Each input must be unique.

Comment: but that's cool for some other parts of my database which I think I am going to use...thanks :)

Comment: @user1141356 - thanks I already added some of those features :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My origianl question was not allowing a value that did not exist from the dropdown which was I figured it our as soon as I asked the question. I had to change

```
mustMatch: false,
```

to

```
mustMatch: true,
```

I editied my original question to ask another relating to the same subject.